# EventToCommand and CommandManagerBinding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

I have a ViewModel which contains a Command which is exposed via the `CommandManager` to other Views.

Now I want to use `EventToCommand` to fire the Command if I double click on a item of a `TreeView` (https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/EventToCommand).

Unfortunate the Command isn't triggered if I use `catel:CommandManagerBinding`, a normal `Binding` to a Command of the ViewModel of the View is working fine. But I need to bind to a Command of another ViewModel.

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to use the CommandManagerBinding without the EventToCommand? In other words, are you sure your command gets registered correctly?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Command for a MenuItem which is doing exactly the same. And it's working fine on the MenuItem.

Comment: Can you please create a small repro so this can be fixed in Catel v5? It should work since the CommandManagerBinding is just a global thing.

Comment: I've created a testproject with this bug https://github.com/HumpaLumpa007/EventToCommand.CommandManagerBinding . I will also create an issue on the github project page

Answer (score 0):

What about using InvokeCommandAction?

Answer (score 0):

*I've responded to the ticket created on the issue tracker, but will put the reply here usability as well.*

*Note this has been tested with Catel v5, but should work with v4 as well.*

I made 2 changes:

1.I *create* the command at startup:

```
var commandManager = ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveType<ICommandManager>();
commandManager.CreateCommand("AddToCollectionCommand");
```

Then I register an action for the command inside the VM:

```
commandManager.RegisterCommand("AddToCollectionCommand", AddToCollectionCommand, this);
```

2.You have to bind the command first, then the command parameter in xaml (order matters, although it shouldn't, but that's a xaml parsing issue we can't fix):

```
<!-- now works! -->
<catel:EventToCommand Command="{catel:CommandManagerBinding AddToCollectionCommand}" 
                                         CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedDataItem}"
                                         DisableAssociatedObjectOnCannotExecute="False" />
```

I recommend that you also look into application-wide command containers. They are extremely powerful and allow you to separate concerns. You can find the docs here:

http://docs.catelproject.com/vnext/catel-mvvm/commands-events/application-wide-commands

If you use Orchestra (see https://github.com/wildgums/orchestra), you can even remap the app-wide commands input gestures with a ready-to-use UI.